# How to know if command line MySQL database import has crashed?

Tags: mysql, command-line

Im importing a 15GB database via the command line on my mac. Its taking a long time and im not sure weather to leave it or if it has crashed. Is there a way to know if MySQL on the command line has crashed?

Update - In my activity monitor I can see the bytes read is very slowly going up. Does this mean that it hasnt crashed?

[image]

Comment: If you are talking about the mysql command line client: it usually outputs one row per query processed. Apart from that: check your process table to see if the mysql daemon is busy or not. An import might take much longer than necessary if you forgot to drop your indexes before the import, since then the index has to be reorganized for each and every insert statement. Instead you should create the indexes after the import has completed.

Comment: How do I check my process table?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the `top` command. Read the "man page" explaining the utility: `man top`

Comment: @arkascha If I enter "top -o cpu" into the terminal I can see mysqld is using most of my CPU. Does this mean it hasn't crashed?

Comment: Sounds like it is processing data to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in to MySQL and run:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

Look for inserts with lots of rows. Do it more than once because you may by chance have caught it it between queries. If you see nothing every time, the import is likely no longer in progress.